# Compare CURL raw data with browser raw data

Tags: php, curl, post, http-headers

I am trying to send POST data using CURL in PHP exactly as browser sends data to once certain page.

The site uses cookie and I get the cookie and send it with my POST request. 
So I am almost sure that I send the exact data with the data that browser sends to the same web page. But I get verification error from the site, so it seems like something is different within these 2 requests.

I see request headers in Chrome and they are identical with the headers that I see with curl_getinfo (excluding the different session cookie id but I am sure that I user right cookie id, because I get it from previous step). Also I checked post data and the data is identical too. Also I use my local machine, so IP address is the same for both browser and curl requests.

However I get error from server for my CURL requests so it seems that the datas have some difference.

My question is not about my code and not about this particular site, but about how to compare raw request from CURL and RAW request form browser to find the difference and then eliminate it?

Comment: Use a packet capture tool like `tcpdump` or `tshark`.

Comment: If possible, put public example of your request, and maybe the cURL code you are using. Remove the private stuff you dont want to publish. It might show something that someone will see and points for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you can check :

### HTTP stuff

- What is the error returned by the server ? If it's an HTTP error, check [what is the reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)
- If you changed the content, be sure you updated the Content-Length
- Some server checks the Referer which might not be set by your script
- Some server checks the User-Agent, be sure you set the same

### Technical stuff

- Are you sure you use the right line ends `\n` or `\r\n` or `\n\r` ?
- Did you ended your HTTP request with an empty line ?
- Try several tools to sniff what you are sending. Barmar suggested `tcpdump` or `tshark`, but `wireshark` is great to see what your script is sending. It it's still identical, double check your browser request with a second tool : Firefox modules like Firebug or `LiveHTTPHeaders` are well integrated in browsers too. Make sure they show the same thing.
- If you try to modify the data you're sending, look at the Tamper Data Firefox module. It's awesome to modify requests on the fly.

Hope this helps.